# Why my code does not work when I assign a function to "name" variable?

Tags: javascript

I am testing this code but something weird happening. It shows an error

> Uncaught Typeerror: name is not a function

but if I change **"name"** to anything else, it works !

```
( name = function (x) {console.log(x || "not set");})();
name ('Rami');
```

**This is the error appearing on Chrome Console**

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Please post the actual error text in the question instead of an image. Images cannot be seen by all devices or locations among other things.

Comment: because it's a variable in your browser (it points to `window.name`)

Comment: @neuhaus no it isn't a keyword

Comment: @neuhaus no. it is not, please read some answers of the post you've linked.

Comment: @neuhaus There is a difference between a reserved keyword and the name of a property associated to an object.

Comment: @Thielicious _if I change name to anything else it works_

Comment: @mplungjan I'm behind a firewall so no images for me. There is also other reason, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 which doesn't only apply to code IMHO

Comment: @mplungjan Depends who you work for :/

Comment: @mplungjan this is besides the point, but i'm pretty sure imgur is on quite a few "default" blacklists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that in a browser context, "name" refers to "window.name" implicitly.

Are you aware that the function gets called twice?

If you just want to return a function pointer, you could use this:

```
name2 = function (x) {console.log(x || "not set");};
name2('Rami');
```

Comment: You can set window.name to a function pointer, but afterwards it will contain a string instead. I guess `window` is magical in that regard.

Comment: Yes this is the right answer. It is not about scope as some people may think. I intended to invoke the function twice.  So I will avoid using "name" .

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function from outside of the [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)'s scope

This would be the correct way to do so:

```
(function() {
  const name = function(name) {
    console.log('Hello ' + name);
  }
  name('Rami');
}());
```

Example: https://repl.it/MX9O

Comment: Also, as the comments above state, the word 'name' is problematic because it has an existing meaning in the parent context. With other labels, the error of calling the function outside the scope may be "fixed" by javascript, the same way it auto adds missing semicolons, etc.

Comment: Having `const name` enclosed inside the IIFE doesn't override the `window.name` property. @arbuthnott

Comment: Correct, but I think that if 'name' does not have a meaning in the parent context (such as `window.name`) then moving the invocation outside the IIFE would be corrected by the code. That is why using other labels (for ex `const myName = ...` might work.

Comment: I wanted the code to be in that syntax. So it was "name" variable issue.